# how to loop through array and display the button as required

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

The req_sent array consists of the ids to whom the friend request was sent.
The req_pending array consists of the ids who received the request and have not yet accepted the friend request. And nonfriends array consists of all friend ids except the logged in persons id. Thus by using if else, I am checking if the nonfriend['id'] == req_sent (id of friend to whom request was sent). Similarly I am checking for req_pending array also. But the button is not displayed in view page as required. Please help.

```
<table class="table class table-bordered table-striped">
    <caption>Nonfriends list table</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Alias</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
        $req_sent = array();
        foreach($request_sent as $request_sent_id)
        {
            $req_sent[] = $request_sent_id['id'];
        }

        $req_pending = array();
        foreach($request_pending as $request_pending_id)
        {
            $req_pending[] = $request_pending_id['id'];
        }

        print_r($nonfriends);


     //print_r($nonfriends);
    foreach($nonfriends as $nonfriend)
    {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $nonfriend["alias"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>"; 

            if($nonfriend['id'] == $req_sent) { ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request Sent</a></button>
           <?php } 

            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

    }
    ?> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can check like this `in_array($nonfriend['id'], $req_sent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `in_array` like below for pending, sent & new requests

```
//print_r($nonfriends);
foreach($nonfriends as $nonfriend)
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $nonfriend["alias"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; 

        if(in_array($nonfriend['id'], $req_pending)) { 
        ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request Pending</a></button>
        <?php 
        } 
        elseif(in_array($nonfriend['id'], $req_sent)) { 
        ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Request Sent</a></button>
        <?php 
        } else {
        ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger"><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">Send Request</a></button>    
        <?php
        }

        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}
```